# Random sound and later system crashes

Tags: sound, 20.04, pulseaudio, alsa, system

My sound crashes after a while. The sound device disappears from alsamixer and pulseaudio. Half a minute later my whole computer starts freezing and in system logs I keep getting repeated messages:

```
System    HDMI1: ASoC: hw_params BE failed -110
Hardware sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: ASoC: can't set iDisp1 Pin hw params: -110
```

rebooting the computer usually fixes the problem if it doesn't freeze on startup. Because sometimes after my display loads I can't do anything and have to force shut down, then wait a few minutes and try again. After a few tries it loads everything normally.

This happens about once or twice a day and I don't know how to recreate this issue because it happens randomly when I'm either talking on discord, playing a game or just browsing the web.

I'm new to linux and ubuntu so I appreciate simple explanations

OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I just deleted pavucontrol and my computer doesn't crash anymore. Sound still crashes, but only if I change the jack from headphone to external speakers.

Comment: Same problem here, thank you. What _pavucontrol_ does?

Comment: Pavucontrol is short for Pulse Audio Volume Control, it just controls what output and input you are using. And it somehow messes with your system sometimes.